# Add annotated documents in one corpus to another

Tags: java, gate

I want to add documents inside one corpus to another corpus or merge two corpora.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I found this answer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/mailman/message/11660787/).

```
for(int i = 0; i < corpus2.size(); i++) {
    Document doc = corpus2.get(i);
    // remove corpus2's reference to loaded doc, but don't sync
    corpus2.unloadDocument(i, false);
    // "un-adopt" doc from old datastore
    doc.setDataStore(null);
    doc.setLRPersistenceId(null);
    // and save it into the new one
    luceneDataStore.adopt(doc);
    luceneDataStore.sync(doc);
    // add to the corpus
    corpus1.add(doc);
    // now we can unload properly
    corpus1.unloadDocument(doc);
    Factory.deleteResource(doc);
}
luceneDataStore.sync(corpus1);
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: This answer is more about: **"How to save documents from one data-store to another"**, which is (in my opinion) much more tricky than just adding all document form one corpus to another. Anyway, thanks for sharing!